# "The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation" error while deploying a solution in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, solution-package, wspbuilder

I am getting following error while trying to deploy solution from SharePoint Central Administration:

> The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system
>   limitation

It happened all of a sudden as it was working fine before.

Also, after this error, I tried to build some solutions, and got the same error there also with failed build operation:

> Error 1   Cryptographic failure while signing assembly '<>' -- 'Error signing assembly -- The requested operation could
>   not be completed due to a file system limitation '

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: is it possible you are hitting an actual "system limitation", e.g. 260 characters in the path or some other NTFS/Windows file system limitation?

Comment: @TiagoDuarte Don't think so. As of now I could understand that it can be because of the heavy disk fragmentation on server.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you didn't deploy from a network share path.
- Make sure that you are not using andy untrusted DLL in your solution and to sign DLL you can check [Signing a Strong Key to an existing DLL that you don’t have its source code](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/03/13/signing-a-strong-key-to-an-existing-dll-that-you-dont-have-the-source-to-it/)
- Manually add the signing DLL file in bin folder of your web application / and in GAC.

Comment: Hi Qassas,     No restore has been made and no untrusted DLL is there in my solution. As I mentioned in the question, it happened all of a sudden. No specific changes has been made. Just one normal functionality code has been checked in before this error occurred while deployment. Also, getting the same error while running the strong key command, as mentioned in link provided by you. Thanks.

Comment: Are you can rollback code check-in and try to check if the issue still exists

Comment: Checked with check-in rollback, but issue still exists. Now facing issues with other solutions as well.